# AppleScript Droplet to Convert PSD and TIF to JPG

Tags: applescript, jpeg, converters, droplet

There are a lot of examples of converters to JPG and i am trying to change one for my needs but i need little help please.
The requirements are:

1. It should be an AppleScript Droplet. I am using Script Editor ( for some reason Automator can't run a simple droplet drag and drop function for me ).
2. The output folder for the JPGs should not be prompted by the user .. but set as a variable in the code permanently and easly changed.
3. The quality ( compression ) of the converted JPG should also have to be easly customisable in the code.
4. The converted JPG files have to be converted to Color profile Adobe RGB 1998 if necessary.

I know Image Events allow us to set the JPG compression like :

`save openedFile as JPEG  with compression level (low|medium|high)`

but unfortunately i need more customisation.

A shell script will help me to set the level from 10 to 100 but unfortunately i can't implement the shell script properly.
Little help please about points 3 and 4.
Thank you !

```
on run
    display dialog "Please drag image files to this script to turn them into JPEGs"
end run
on open draggeditems
    set End_Folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:zzz:Desktop:End"
    
    repeat with currentFile in draggeditems
        tell application "Image Events"
            set openedFile to open (currentFile as alias)
            set fileLocation to the location of openedFile
            set fileName to the name of openedFile
            set Path_to_Converted_File to (End_Folder & ":" & text 1 thru -5 of fileName & ".jpg")

            do shell script "sips --setProperty formatOptions 10 " & openedFile
            
    save openedFile as JPEG in Path_to_Converted_File
            --save openedFile as JPEG  with compression level low  in Path_to_Converted_File (low|medium|high)
            
            close openedFile
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing up **Image Events** and `sips` is more confusing than useful, and since `sips` can perform the various options you are looking for (such as 3 & 4), it makes more sense to use it for everything.  Setting a few variables for the various options will let you change them as needed, or if adding preferences or whatever.  The `sips` man page will give you more details about the various options; I’ve added comments for the ones used in the following script:

```
on run
    open (choose file with prompt "Select image files to turn into JPEGs:" with multiple selections allowed)
end run

on open draggeditems
    set destination to (((path to desktop folder) as text) & "End:") -- folder path (trailing delimiter)
    set format to "jpeg" -- jpeg | tiff | png | gif | jp2 | pict | bmp | qtif | psd | sgi | tga
    set extension to ".jpg" -- extension to match format
    set compression to 10 -- low | normal | high | best | <percent>
    set profile to quoted form of "/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/AdobeRGB1998.icc" -- POSIX path to color profile
    repeat with thisFile in draggeditems
        set theName to justTheName for thisFile
        set originalFile to quoted form of POSIX path of thisFile
        set convertedFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (destination & theName & extension)
        do shell script "sips -s format " & format & " -s formatOptions " & compression & " -m " & profile & space & originalFile & " --out " & convertedFile
    end repeat
end open

on justTheName for filePath
    tell application "System Events" to tell disk item (filePath as text)
        set {fileName, extension} to {name, name extension}
    end tell
    if extension is not "" then set fileName to text 1 thru -((count extension) + 2) of fileName -- just the name part
    return fileName
end justTheName
```

Edited to add:
The shell script is expecting POSIX paths, so the aliases passed to the `open` handler are coerced and quoted in the event they contain spaces.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is very well written but unfortunately i can't make it work.
I've changed only:
`set destination to ((("/Users/zzz/Desktop/") as text) & "End")`
The result:
The pictures have been overwritten in a jpg format with theyr name being xxx.psd for example. I can open them only if .psd is renamed to .jpg. There is nothing going to the End folder.
And very strangely the applied color profile is sRGB even that the Path correctly leads to AdobeRGB1998.icc color profile file.
I've debugged the variables with "display dialog" command and they look fine.

Comment: Not sure what is happening - I tested with formats .jpg, .png, .psd, and .tiff, using ExifTool and Spotlight to look at the color profiles and file type, and everything works as expected in my Big Sur system.  The file will only be overwritten if it is in the same destination folder, and then only if it has the same extension as the converted file.  You can also look at the shell script command to see if that appears to be OK.  You should not have had to change the destination, it will use the folder "End" on the current user's desktop - were any other changes made?

Comment: I'm on Sierra if that makes a difference. In the 'do shell' line, try changing '-o' to '--out'. I also changed the variable 'format' as I was getting errors.

Comment: OK, fired up my Sierra machine, and the `sips` version there has a different function for the `-o` option.  Changing it to `--out` works, so I’ve edited my answer to use that.  It sounds like you may be using a scripting addition that is introducing a terminology conflict (can’t use additions in recent OS versions without some gymnastics) - there shouldn’t be a problem with changing variable names to avoid something like that (or personal preference).

Comment: @OutOfTouch I think that your problem is that there is a conflict with your 'destination' and the 'set convertedFile' line. You're using a posix style path but the 'set convertedFile' line begins with an HFS path and converts to posix style — note the colon that is inserted in that line. So try the original 'set destination' line as it produces the correct output to feed the other line. That said, it might be clearer if the colon was added after 'End' in the 'set destination' line rather than than where it is.

Comment: @Mockman - Good point, although common practice is to use the built-in paths to avoid hard-coding user names. I can edit that though, if it makes more sense.

Comment: @red_menace No, I think you're right, that's why I think OutOfTouch should use your 'path to desktop' line (plus it works). But if the colon were attached to 'End' in that line, it would clarify that 'End' is a directory as well as reduce the number of '&' in the 'set convertedFile' line. It's a minor point though.

Comment: @red_menace Mockman Thank you guys. I end up using red_menace version but more importantly i've learned a lot about simp and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong in your script. It is not clear why you are opening the file for writing before sending it to a shell command. sips does not operate on open FILE references. sips will need  to open the file from a POSIX path. I think this may do what you want (you will need to implement error checking, etc.):

```
on open draggeditems
    set End_Folder to "~/Desktop/End/"
    repeat with currentFile in draggeditems
        do shell script "sips --setProperty formatOptions 10 " & quoted form of POSIX path of currentFile & " --out " & End_Folder
    end repeat
end open
```

Comment: @red_menace Excuse me but i need a little bit of update on this converter. I would like the Paths in the original image to be saved after the file is converted. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: @Mockman Excuse me but i need a little bit of update on this converter. I would like the Paths in the original image to be saved after the file is converted. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: @OutOfTouch It is unclear what you are asking for. Where do you want the path to be saved? Or do you want the new file to be saved a the same location as the old file?

Comment: @epooch By Paths i mean the Paths inside the Picture from which we are making selections in Photoshop :). I see the confusion there. Sorry. I need the Paths inside the original image not to be deleted once the picture is converted.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited red_menace's code to make it save the JPEGs into the same folder as the files you drag to it. The 'on run' function has been removed so save this as an app and drag and drop the files to it.

This is so much more efficient than going through Photoshop!

```
on open draggeditems
    --DEFINE DESTINATION FOLDER
    tell application "System Events"
        --set destination to (((path to desktop folder) as text) & "End:") -- folder path (trailing delimiter)
        --set destination to ((path to downloads folder) as text)
        --MAKE IT SAME AS SOURCE FILES
        set thisFile to item 1 of draggeditems
        set theFolder to (container of thisFile)
        set destination to path of theFolder as alias as text
    end tell
    set format to "jpeg" -- jpeg | tiff | png | gif | jp2 | pict | bmp | qtif | psd | sgi | tga
    set extension to ".jpg" -- extension to match format
    set compression to 10 -- low | normal | high | best | <percent>
    set profile to quoted form of "/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/AdobeRGB1998.icc" -- POSIX path to color profile
    repeat with thisFile in draggeditems
        set theName to justTheName for thisFile
        set originalFile to quoted form of POSIX path of thisFile
        set convertedFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (destination & theName & extension)
        --log convertedFile
        do shell script "sips -s format " & format & " -s formatOptions " & compression & " -m " & profile & space & originalFile & " --out " & convertedFile
    end repeat
end open

on justTheName for filePath
    tell application "System Events" to tell disk item (filePath as text)
        set {fileName, extension} to {name, name extension}
    end tell
    if extension is not "" then set fileName to text 1 thru -((count extension) + 2) of fileName -- just the name part
    return fileName
end justTheName
```